# Opposite of code golf

Tags: discussion

Is there a version of code golf that requires the most convoluted solution instead of the tersest?

I think it might be humorous (and informative) to see answers that exemplify the worst of some languages and architectures.

Rules:

- largest code base wins
- scoring is the same as golf (byte count, omit scaffolding (e.g. `using`s in c#))
- all code must pertain to the solution (no superfluous code)

If the code base is sufficiently large, it might be better to post a gist or otherwise link to the code.

Comment: The problem is rule number 3. We're not aware of an objective definition of "superfluous code" that effectively prevents arbitrarily large solutions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. It's called [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling).

Comment: You just made my day.  Thanks.  Will mark as answer when I can.

Answer (score 8):

Elaborating on Mego's answer a little, the tag you're looking for is [code-bowling](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-bowling). However, there aren't that many questions with that tag, because:

1. The challenge quickly spirals out of control with astronomical byte counts
2. It takes a lot of effort to enforce challenges so that they don't follow 1
3. Restraints can be somewhat ambiguous, so that ambiguity is taken out of context, which therefore turns the challenge into 1

It's a lot of effort, but if you can pull something like that off, then you've definitely got a good challenge!

Answer (score 2):

Since no one else has mentioned it, it sounds like you'd be interested in the [The International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://www.ioccc.org/). It's all about incredibly complicated, unreadable code. They don't make any claims about objectivity, they appoint judges who spend a long time working through solutions - one of the reasons they only run it every couple of years.

Some of the prizewinners are pretty amazing though - well worth a look.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll check it out.

Comment: @gregsdennis See also the Obfuscated Perl Contest, one of the winners is mentioned [in this essay](https://www.stilldrinking.org/programming-sucks) (ctrl-f "Mayan") although the entire essay is worth a read.

Comment: Another great one is (was) the : [underhanded C context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underhanded_C_Contest) (where programs have to do what is asked of them and appear complitely innocuous, but contain a "bug" that maliciously does something bad in certain conditions) : it is very eye-opening on the dangers of programming (closed or open source)